# Will_Paginate is it possible to let the user select the # of paginated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a paginated list, and a select box of numbers showing how many pages to display. When the user picks a value I want the screen to refresh with the resized list.

View:

```
<%= select_tag :paginate_size, options_for_select([['Display: 5', 5],['Display: 10',10],['Display: 20', 20],['Display: 30', 30],['Display: 50', 50],['Display: 100',100]]), :onchange => remote_function(:url => {:action => :show_my_entries}, :with =>"'paginate_size='+value")%>
```

When I select a value I can see in the log that the show_my_entries function is being called and sent the paginate_size parameter.

In the controller I set the per_page variable as shown below, however selecting anything in the list doesn't refresh the screen with the new list size:

```
def show_my_entries
 if (params[:paginate_size].nil?)
      paginate_size = 8
    else
      paginate_size = params[:paginate_size]
    end

    @entries = Entry.find_all_my_entries_by_pub(session[:publication_id], session[:user_id])

    @entries_paginate = Entry.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'title', :per_page => paginate_size, :conditions => "publication_id = " + session[:publication_id].to_s + " AND writer_id = " + session[:user_id].to_s

    render :layout => "dashboard"

  end
```

Comment: can you put the HTML generate by your helper ? I think all is inside.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `:update` parameter in the `remote_function` which should point to the id of the HTML element containing the entries list.

So, if the content is, for example, done like this:

```
<div id="my_entries">
   <%= print_entries_list %>
</div>
```

Your remote function should be like this:

```
remote_function(:update => "my_entries", :url => {:action => :show_my_entries}, :with =>"'paginate_size='+value")
```